# Selenium: moveByOffset() not working

Tags: java, selenium

Facing the issue with `moveByOffset()` method.

on this [link](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) I can move the slider to right side, but when I tried to move it back on the left side its just not moving. Tell me if there is an issue with `moveByOffset()` method or should I use any other method.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class JquerySlider {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver=null;
    try {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Slider']")).click();

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/span"));

            for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                actions.clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(i, 0).build().perform();
            }

            //WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/span"));

            /*for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("For 2 "+i);
                actions.clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(0,0).release().build().perform();
            }*/ This part is not working...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();

    }


}
```

}

I'm new to Selenium and trying to working on it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope `moveByOffset(0,0)` is a copy-paste problem and not your actual problem? You want to use `moveByOffset(-i, 0)` or something.

Comment: oh yes, `moveByOffset(i,0)` is actual method.

Comment: I just tried it with the newest Selenium, Chrome and Chromedriver ... and it works correctly, copy-pasted verbatim from your code :(. Define "does not work". Does it not click, does it not move, do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to move the slider back, you should use this code:

```
actions.clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(-i,0).release().build().perform();
```

in your second for.

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be that you have .release() in the second for loop?  The loop will count down correctly I think based on the offset method, but I think the release method call may cause the Action to release the drag